# How to convert multiple letters to uppercase in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I need to change all lowercase letters e, s, t, and a to uppercase letters in a text file in vim. I tried using `:%s/e/E/g` for all letters but I couldn't find a better solution. I want to do it using the command, not via visual method.

Comment: I need to know if you're trying to convert the case of every letter specified, or just the firsts letters specified for each word?

Comment: The former viz. every letter individually needs to be capitalized in the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this using `%s`.Capture the pattern first; and then change the captured pattern to uppercase.:

`&` is whole captured pattern

`\U` change to uppercase

```
:%s/[esta]/\U&/g
```

If you are on linux system you can also use `tr`. `!` denotes shell command.

```
:%!tr esta ESTA
```